# qcircuit: dashed wire through a block gate

Tags: qcircuit

Consider the modifying the circuit in [the documentation for `qcircuit`](https://physics.unm.edu/CQuIC/Qcircuit/Qtutorial.pdf) on page 3 where the `\mathcal{F}` gate spans 6 wires: source code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,qcircuit}

\begin{document}
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=0em {
  & \multigate{5}{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw
}
\end{document}
```

and the image renders as

[image: original image]

Suppose I wanted to show a faint/dashed wire passing through the gate's box where second wire from the top would be, were there no gate (to indicate, say, that `\mathcal{F}` acts on the 1st and 3rd–6th wires but not the 2nd). e.g.:

[image: dash]
[image: grey]

Is there a way to do this with `qcircuit`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you extend and clarify your question a bit? Please copy the code from the documentation in your question, in the form of a compilable example (i.e., including `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This ensures that the question remains useful in the future when the link stops working or the exampe is no longer on page 3 because the documentation has changed. Moreover, it makes it easier for people that attempt to answer your question to start, without needing to look up a pdf, copying, cleaning up and adding code.

Comment: Furthermore, please add a mock-up image of your desired output (for example made with a drawing program like Paint on Windows), currently it is difficult to understand for people that don't know anything about (quantum) circuits but that might still know how to answer because they know about XY-pic or LaTeX drawing in general.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the post to reflect these remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `qcircuit` package uses `\xymatrix` from the `xy-pic` package to draw the circuits. The example circuit from the manual is a 3x6 matrix, with the wire ends and the (horizontal) center of the gate as the middle of the cells.

Because a circuit is actually a matrix, you can use syntax from `xy-pic` within the circuit. Here a useful command is `*!` which prints non-centered content within a matrix cell. In the cell where you want to draw the connected wire you can draw a `\hdashrule` from the `dashrule` package to get a dashed line. Unfortunately the rule was 1/3 of a point too high (!) so you can lower it using the first optional argument of `\hdashrule`. The second optional argument controls the appearance at the start and end of the rule, here the value `x` or `c` leads to better horizontal alignment.

Then you draw the two wires as normal with `\qw` commands. The only issue is the height of the row, which is normally accounted for by `\ghost{}`. Internally this command uses `*+` from `xy-pic`, which reserves a box of a certain height and width. We can copy the definition from qcircuit, which is `*+<1em,.9em>`, however we only want to adjust the height so the first coordinate should be zero (i.e., `*+<0em,.9em>`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,qcircuit}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\begin{document}
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=0em {
  & \multigate{5}{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
*+<0em,0.9em>{} & *!{\hdashrule[-0.3pt][x]{1.9em}{0.5pt}{1pt}}\qw & \qw\\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw \\
  & \ghost{\mathcal{F}} & \qw
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]